# PrimeFaces Starter Project

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have some issue with **Java EE** using **NetBeans** and primefaces.

**index.xhtml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui>
      xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
      template="/webpages/resources/template.xhtml"
    <h:head>

      <title>Reservation</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/jsfcrud.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="resources/css/styles.css"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h3>Reservation Page</h3>
         <style type="text/css">
    .label {
        width:20%;
        padding:4px;
    }

    .value {
        width:80%;
        padding:4px;
    }

    .grid {
        width:100%;
    }

    .error {
        color: red;
    }

    .outputLabel {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .grid {
        width:33%;
        padding:4px;
    }
</style>


<h:form>

    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true"/>

    <p:wizard flowListener="#{userWizard.onFlowProcess}">
        <p:tab id="customer" title="Customer Details">
            <p:panel header="Customer Details">
                <p:messages />
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                    <h:outputText value="Firstname: *" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.firstName}" required="true" label="Firstname"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Lastname: *" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.lastName}" required="true" label="Lastname"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.age}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Birthday: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.birthday}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Email: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.email}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userWizard.skip}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="address" title="Address">
            <p:panel header="Address Details">
                <p:messages />
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                    <h:outputText value="Zip Code: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.zipcode}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Country: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.country}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Adress: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.adress}" />

                    <h:outputText value="City: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.adress}" />

                    <h:outputText value="State: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.adress}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userWizard.skip}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>


         <p:tab id="room" title="Room Selection">
            <p:panel header="Room Selection">
                <p:messages />
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="label, value">
                    <h:outputText value="Selecione o número do quarto: *" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.roomNumber}" required="true" label="Email"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Selecion a dimensão do quarto(10m²,20m²,40m²: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.dimensionRoom}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Informações adicionais para o quarto: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.info}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="reservation" title="Reservation">
            <p:panel header="Reservation Selection">
                <p:messages />
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                    <h:outputText value="Number of guests?: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.numberGuests}" required="true"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Entre com o dia da sua Reserva: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.reservationDate}"/>

                     <h:outputText value="Entre com a data do seu Check-in: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.checkIn}"/>

                     <h:outputText value="Entre com a data do seu Check-out: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.checkOut}"/>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="confirm" title="Confirmation">
            <p:panel header="Confirmation">
                <h:panelGrid id="confirmation" columns="3" columnClasses="grid,grid,grid">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                        <h:outputText value="Firstname: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.firstName}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Lastname: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.lastName}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.age}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                            <h:outputText value="Email: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.email}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Adress: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.adress}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Zipcode: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.zipcode}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                        <h:outputText value="Country: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.country}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Title " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.title}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="City: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.city}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                            <h:outputText value="State: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.state}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Birthday: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.birthday}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Room Number: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.roomNumber}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                        <h:outputText value="Dimension Room: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.dimensionRoom}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Info: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.info}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Number of Guests: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.numberGuests}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                        <h:outputText value="Reservation Date: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.reservationDate}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Check-in: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.checkIn}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>

                        <h:outputText value="Check-out: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userWizard.user.checkOut}" styleClass="outputLabel"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{userWizard.save}" update="growl" process="@this"/>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>

</h:form>

        <br />
        <h:link outcome="/customer/List" value="Show All Customer Items"/>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

**pom.xml**

I'm actually using maven.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The error that appears is that:

> A component is undeclared

and asks to add this library:

```
xmlns: p = "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

but when added, it does not resolve and asks to put back in a infinite loop.

[image]

Comment: Try removing as much from your xhtml as possible in such a way that in the end you have max 10-15 lines and the error us still there. (Your xhtml is totally invalid btw)

Comment: Have a look at https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/gettingstarted/helloworld

Comment: And please read [ask] (again?) And [tour] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough` is not PrimeFaces at all

Comment: (nor is the non-prefixed, out of element/tag older than prehistoric PrimeFaces namespace, which is part of the 'totally invalid')

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces namespace link is `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"`.

Also, I don't see any primefaces dependencies in your pom.xml you posted.

Look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/getstarted.xhtml

Have a nice day.